# double-backslash-file path problem@version 10.0

Tags: front-end

I found this happen @ *Mathematica 10* pre test version and formal English version.

- Copy a file from windows, then paste into FrontEnd cell, you'll get a path, such like

  `"C:\\Users\\Hyper\\Documents\\b"`

This is Ok.

However, in the Chinese character case

```
"C:\\Users\\Hyper\\Documents\\新建文件夹"
```

This is bad. [It's fine before version 10.0]

- choose a file then Shift+Right-Mouse-Click, and `Copy as path`, then paste into FrontEnd cell, you'll get a path, such like

  `file1="C:\Users\Hyper\Documents\b"`

  `file2="C:\Users\Hyper\Documents\新建文件夹"`

  `file3="C:\Users\Hyper\Documents\b\新建文件夹"`

So, two methods to get path from windows system both work badly, ie

`FileExistsQ[file1]==>False`

`FileExistsQ[file2]==>True`

`FileExistsQ[file3]==>False`

I have many old files in Chinese path, they cannot be dealt conveniently by *Mathematica 10.0*@Windows now.

I should manually delete a backslash in the path string, and if I use another method to get file path, \b, \hello these names are annoying.

[image]

Is this a simple bug? Why not just keep it the same as that in Version 9?

Comment: Could you describe what is bad with the Chinese character path? Are the characters supposed to be escaped or so?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I should manually delete a backslash in the path string, and if I use another method to get file path, `\b`, `\hello` these names are annoying.